# Why is there a sharp elbow in my ROC curves?

Tags: r, roc, discriminant-analysis

I have some EEG data sets that I am testing against two classes. I can get a decent error rate from LDA (the class-conditional distributions aren't Gaussian, but have similar tails and good enough separation), and so I want to plot the ROC of the LDA predictor against data sets from other subjects.

Here is a typical graph for the predictor tested against a single trial:
[image]

I have tried a couple of different packages (pROC and ROCR), and the results are consistent. My question is, what's with the sharp elbow? Is it just an artifact of the projection produced by the LDA, i.e., there happens to be a 'cliff' where the classifier performance plummets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A perfect ROC "curve" will be shaped with a sharp bend.  The performance you have there is very near perfect separation.  In addition, it looks like you have a scarcity of points making the curve.

Comment: Yeah, each of these is only around 7500 time samples in 14 dimensions (unprojected space). That said, if I had a bunch of trials from different subjects, wouldn't noise eventually smooth the curve out around the inflection point?

Comment: When you say "each of these" I don't know what you mean.  It's unclear how many points actually make up the curve.  Yes, perhaps it would curve if there was variability among subjects but if there isn't then it won't.  It's possible you have a data coding issue or you're only actually plotting a couple of samples but it's impossible to tell from what you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, I meant each individual time series (experimental trial). There is quite a bit of variability among subjects, but the resulting ROC for each test of a single predictor on a trial has a sharp corner like the above picture, just locatedin a slightly different place. I double-checked the size of my predictor and response inputs to the roc() command; both are length 7500 class labels.

Answer (score 6):

Although this question was asked about 3 years ago, I find it useful to answer it here after coming across it and getting puzzled by it for some time. When your ground truth output is 0,1 and your prediction is 0,1, you get an angle-shape elbow. If your prediction or ground truth are confidence values or probabilities (say in the range [0,1]), then you will get curved elbow.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with John, in that the sharp curve is due to a scarcity of points. Specifically, it appears that you used your model's binary predictions (i.e. 1/0) and the observed labels (i.e. 1/0). Because of this, you have 3 points, one assumes a cutoff of Inf, one assumes a cutoff of 0, and the last assumes a cutoff of 1 which is given to you by your model's TPR and FPR and is located at the sharp angle in your graph.

Instead, you should be using the probabilities of the predicted class (values between 0 and 1) and the observed labels (i.e. 1/0). This will then give you a number of points on the graph that is equal to the number of unique probabilities you have (plus one for Inf). So if you have 100 unique probabilities, you will then 101 points on the graph for each of the various cutoffs.

Comment: Sadly, I don't remember which specific calculation or data I was using, so I can't go back through it. That sounds like excellent advice however.